# Let X be any non-empty set, and prove that in the lattice of all topologies on X each chain has atmost one compact hausdorff topology as a member.

Tags: general-topology

Let X be any non-empty set, and prove that in the lattice of all topologies on X each chain has atmost one compact hausdorff topology as a member.
Here discrete topology will not work. Here what is the supremum & infimum in between two topologies & how do I construct the chain?

Comment: Don't bother about the chains. If $c_1,c_2$ are compact Hausdorff topologies, the claim is that if $c_1$ is finer than $c_2$, then in fact $c_1 = c_2$.

Comment: Infimum of topologies is just the intersection, supremum is the topology with the union as a subbasis. But see Daniel Fischer's comment.

Answer (score 2):

If there are two compact hausdorff topos in a chain then they are same. Because a 1-1 continuous mapping of a compact space onto a Hausdorff space is homeomorphism.